# Is amazon EC2 micro instance enough for simple node.js and redis setup?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, redis

I'm developing a very simple portfolio web site. It will most likely barely have any traffic. I want to use node.js and redis for the backend of the application.

Since amazon ec2 has 1 year free of micro instance, I was wondering if it will be good enough to host both redis and node.js on it.

As I said the site will be very lightweight and not accessed frequently.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Its free for a year

Comment: I will try it, I just wanted to see if people have already experience with similar setup:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A micro instance has been more than enough for my own site which runs nginx, wordpress, django, and a few other random things.

I'm sure it will be more than adequate for what your doing (unless it's number or IO intensive.. and if you don't know, it's probably not). And hey, it's free, so why not? AWS has a lot of cool features you can play with too!

Answer (score 1):

The specs from [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) lead me to believe so.

Obviously the redis is questionable with the allotted RAM but it should be fine for minimal traffic.

613 MiB memory
Up to 2 EC2 Compute Units (for short periodic bursts)
EBS storage only
32-bit or 64-bit platform
I/O Performance: Low
EBS-Optimized Available: No
API name: t1.micro

Answer (score 0):

My understanding says that it's free for the new users, so just put your code up there and check what happens. Other way is that it only provides around 650 mb of RAM. So you should be fine at the start. Only when a lot of data gets generated by users, the RAM will become bottle neck.